# SIP Investment Question

Tags: india, etf, nse-india

I am 30 now (**India**) and planning to invest 1000Rs SIP monthly for my Child. My plan is to increase this 10% every year and invest only in NIFTYBEES ETF.

This is purely long-term (more than 30 years) and I will continue investing for 25 years post which my son can continue the same for his retirement.

Is this possible to do? what are the things I should take care before initiating this?

Thanks

Comment: Whose name will be on the account? Yours? Your child's name with you as custodian till the child comes of age? You and your child jointly? Whose PAN Card number will be on the account?

Comment: I am planning to add it under my account as I don't know how to create account for my kid and all.. And after he reaches 21 or so, I will hand-it over to him (may be I'll look if there is an option to transfer at that time)